# Reverse-engineer interval of rolling average without underlying data?

Tags: statistics, average

Is it possible to analyse a set of numbers and determine the likelihood that they are a rolling average, and if so, what it's duration might be?

My source data is from a website which provides estimated audience sizes for advertisers.  These figures change daily - my theory is they are based on a rolling average of X previous days and it would be very useful to figure out how long a period that is.

I have been collecting data for several months, and have daily figures (sequences of 150+ days) for hundreds of topics (plenty of which follow a similar day-to-day trend when you plot them alongside each other).

But I have none of the original data points (whatsoever), and no information about the methodology the site is using.

If there are any techniques I can use to spot patterns, could someone point me in the right direction?

(One thing I notice is where the predicted audience size is low, I see a lot of figures like 997, 998, 999 or 664, 665…  Would analysing the frequency of these help at all?)

Comment: Well, the differences between successive rolling average points is (up to a constant) the difference between the daily numbers at the start and the stop of the period.  If you have some prior knowledge of the daily data (like, maybe, that it is noise about its mean) then you should see that these differences reflect that.

Comment: Should say:  be careful of the Garbage In Garbage Out problem.  If, in fact, you have no information regarding the daily data and are just hoping to learn about that this way, then I'd say there was no chance of succeeding along these lines.  There are lots and lots of things somebody might be measuring, and just guessing at the nature of the data, with no way to test your guesses, is unlikely to be productive.

Comment: I agree with @lulu and want to add that it may be more beneficial for you to reach out to the administrator/maintainer/developer of the website and see if they can help you give helpful meaning to the data you have.